# an 'Help' commands that auto generate a help for a commands.group subcommand using this function

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried to make a help commands, but i don't know how can I create the help commands for a commands group, which is the main command is separated with the groups, I tried to do `help modmail channel` modmail is the group, and channel was the sub commands, it just says that command not exist
**This is the function:**

> Please note that, I'm not asking how to use the commands.group, I'm asking about how can I use my function to create **a help for Subcommands on commands.group()**

```
    async def cmdhelp(self, ctx, command):
        params = []
        for key, value in command.params.items():
            if key not in ("self", "ctx"):
                params.append(f"[{key}]" if "NoneType" in str(value) else f"<{key}>")
        params = " ".join(params)
        alias = ", ".join(command.aliases)
        commandhelp = command.help
        commanddesc = command.description
        if not command.help:
            commandhelp = "`None`"
        if not command.description:
            commanddesc = "`None`"
        if not command.aliases:
            alias = "`None`"
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Help for {command}",
                              colour=0x59FFE7,
                              description=f"**Description:**\n{commandhelp}\n**Usage:**\n`{command} {params}`\n**Aliases:**\n`{alias}`\n**Permission:**\n`{commanddesc}`")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
    async def help(self, ctx, *,cmd=None):
        if cmd is None:
           # lets say this is a embed with a help category list
        else:
            if (command := get(self.bot.commands, name=cmd)):
                await self.cmdhelp(ctx, command)

            else:
                await ctx.send("That command does not exist.")
```

Examples:
[image: The example of help command I'm trying to make]
If you see, it works with normal command which is `help modmail` but how can I make for the **subcommand of modmail** group? which is `help modmail channel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, that isn't the proper way to use subcommands.  This is how to use them:

```py
client.remove_command("help")

@client.group()
async def main_cmd(ctx):
    print("main command")

@main_cmd.command()
async def sub_cmd(ctx):
    print("subcommand")
```

Saying `main_cmd` in discord will just print `"main command"`, but saying `main_cmd sub_cmd` in discord will print `"main command"` and then `"subcommand"`.

If you don't want the original command to run if a subcommand is invoked, use `ctx.invoked_subcommand`:

```py
client.remove_command("help")

@client.group()
async def main_cmd(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand != None:
        return
    print("main command")

@main_cmd.command()
async def sub_cmd(ctx):
    print("subcommand")
```

EDIT (after the question was edited):
To create "commands" (it won't really be a command) for each command in the bot, use `bot.commands`:

```
client.remove_command("help")

@client.command(description = "THIS IS THE MESSAGE THAT WILL APPEAR IN THE SPECIFIC HELP COMMAND")
async def a_command(ctx):
    pass #look at the decorator

@client.command()
async def help(ctx, cmd = None):
    if cmd == None:
        await ctx.send("DEFAULT HELP")
    elif cmd in (cmds := {command.name: command for command in client.commands}):
        await ctx.send("cmd: " + cmds[cmd].description)
    else:
        await ctx.send("command not found")
```

This creates "subcommands" for each command in the bot.

Comment: Hey, sorry but i didn't ask for this, if you see my code isn't displaying as a command.group() because thats not the main problem, the main problem is how can i make a help commands with function that i just write for my subcommands, i already know how to make a subcommands properly :/ I've edited my post if you don't understand

Comment: (In my example) instead of putting `@main_cmd.command()`, put `@main_cmd.group()`.  Then you can use the decorator `@sub_cmd.command()` to make subcommands of the subcommand.

Comment: I didn't understand about what are you talking about, I alr know about it dude, I just want it to generate a help command using `async def cmdhelp(self, ctx, cmd)` so I don't need to create a new commands group for a help command, please read the question carefully.

Comment: What do you mean "read it carefully" you edited the question after I answered.  I'll edit mine to do what you want though.

Comment: If you see on my question, i already created the specific help cmds with my function, and I didn't edit the question to something different, I only clarify what I need, if you see the revisions, I'm trying to explain the problems not trying to change the question, the problem is the function (spesific help)  isn't working for a subcommand, for example: `.help modmail channel` but you answered with how to make a subcommand or commands group properly :/ I appreciated it, but that's not the main question `;-;`

Comment: Some of it helps me ;)